# Installing RMagick gem on Mountain Lion show errors 'Abort trap: 6'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems, imagemagick, rmagick

I've installed ImageMagick(6.8.6-3) by Homebrew.
When try to install rmagick gem(**2.13.2**) on Max OS X Mountain Lion, show errors '**Abort trap: 6**'

```
gem install rmagick -v 2.13.2
Abort trap: 6
```

When switch version to '**2.13.1**', show errors below.

```
gem install rmagick -v 2.13.1
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/Macmini/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for /usr/bin/gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... no
checking for sys/types.h... no
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no

Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find MagickWand.h.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/Macmini/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Macmini/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@sis/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Macmini/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@sis/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

I can't figure out what's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

to install `rmagick 2.13.1` on mac, you need Imagemagick version 6.7.x (it wont work with 6.8.x). And you may have to run this command before installing the gem

```
cd "`Magick-config --prefix`/lib"; ln -s libMagick++-Q8.7.dylib libMagick++.dylib; ln -s libMagickCore-Q8.7.dylib libMagickCore.dylib; ln -s libMagickWand-Q8.7.dylib libMagickWand.dylib
```

The above is actually equivalent of running these commands

```
cd "`Magick-config --prefix`lib"
ln -s libMagick++-Q16.7.dylib   libMagick++.dylib
ln -s libMagickCore-Q16.7.dylib libMagickCore.dylib
ln -s libMagickWand-Q16.7.dylib libMagickWand.dylib
```

After this, you can

```
gem install rmagick -v '2.13.1'
```

**And to install ImageMagick 6.7 using homebrew**, run these commands

```
cd /usr/local/
brew versions imagemagick
```

You should see something like this

```
6.8.0-10 git checkout 883f549 /usr/local/Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
6.7.7-6  git checkout 834ce4a /usr/local/Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
6.7.5-7  git checkout f965101 /usr/local/Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
6.7.1-1  git checkout be8e0ff /usr/local/Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
6.6.9-4  git checkout 4e7c332 /usr/local/Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
6.6.7-10 git checkout 0476235 /usr/local/Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
6.6.7-8  git checkout db99927 /usr/local/Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
6.6.7-1  git checkout 7cd042f /usr/local/Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
6.6.4-5  git checkout 53886de /usr/local/Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
```

Then choose your version by running

```
git checkout 834ce4a /usr/local/Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
```

followed by

```
brew install imagemagick
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I've done all commands as you shown but nothing has changed. 
I've got the same error....

Comment: I've copied older gem files and installed older ImageMagick and XQuarz did the trick! Your instruction for choose ImageMagick version is really helpful. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: you are most welcome. You can also show your appreciation with an upvote + accepting the answer.